# Reading two files and then finding the growth rate

Tags: java

I need help trying to read two files that have the census from 2010 and 2000. I have to read both files and then find out the population growth between those two files. I keep getting null for ever single state. I know that I have null for inLine1 and inLine2.

The file looks like this

```
Alabama,4779736
Alaska,710231
Arizona,6392017
Arkansas,2915918
```

### Code:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class pa10
{
  public static void main(String[] args, char[] inLine2, char[] inLine1)
    throws java.io.IOException
  {
    String fileName1 = "Census2000growth.txt";
    String fileName2 = "Census2010growth.txt";
    int i;

    File f = new File("Census2010growth.txt");
    if(!f.exists()) {
        System.out.println( "file does not exist ");
    }
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(f);
    infile.useDelimiter ("[\t|,|\n|\r]+"); //create a delimiter 
    final int MAX = 51;
    int [] myarray = new int [MAX];
    String[] statearray = new String[MAX];
    int fillsize;

      // set up input stream1
    FileReader fr1 = new
        FileReader(fileName1);
      // buffer the input stream
    BufferedReader br1 =
        new BufferedReader(fr1);

      // set up input stream2
    FileReader fr2 = new
        FileReader(fileName2);
      // buffer the input stream
    BufferedReader br2 =
        new BufferedReader(fr2);

      // read and display1
    String buffer1 = "";

    ArrayList<String> firstFile1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((buffer1 = br1.readLine()) != null) {
        firstFile1.add(buffer1);
      System.out.println(inLine1);  // display the line
  }
  br1.close();



    //Now read the second file or make for this separate method
      // read and display2
    String buffer2 = "";

    ArrayList<String> firstFile2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((buffer2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {
        firstFile2.add(buffer2);
      System.out.println(inLine2);  // display the line
  }
  br2.close();

    //Read all the lines in array or list
    //After that you can calculate them.
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the `BufferedReader` documentation. Your file isn't formatted with the types of line separators it is expecting. I suggest using a `Scanner` and setting the line separator to the appropriate pattern, or using `String.split`

Comment: The thing is I need two different arrays. I am new to this programing so I am having a hard time.

Comment: @GoingBubbaLong Actually you just edited your post again. The format that you're now showing SHOULD work with a BufferedReader. Please make sure to give all relevant info when you first post ...

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new to this website

Answer (score 0):

You have two different variables, `buffer1` and `inline1`. Since you never set the value of `inline1`, it will always be `null`.